# How do I create radio buttons based on other table of database value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.1.5

I have a table name "API" and has "status" column.

How do I create form_for radio buttons base on status data in view template?

Comment: probably you can add more details to your question by adding you `schema` or code you are trying to use

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example

```
<% form_for(...) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :status, 'alpha' %> 
  <%= f.radio_button :status, 'beta' %>
<% end %>
```

For more details you should check the [`radio_button`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button) helper documentation.